# emacs magit: git-dir is not in the default place

Tags: emacs, magit

If `git-dir` is not in work-tree, we can use the command line

```
git --work-tree=/a/b --git-dir=/c/d/ status
```

to run git. How can we use magit in this situation?
Thanks.

Comment: See the `magit-git-global-arguments` variable? (possibly only in in Magit 2.1.0+)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a file `/path/to/worktree/.git` with contents `gitdir: /path/to/gitdir` and in `/path/to/gitdir/config` set `core.worktree` to `/path/to/worktree`. You can also use relative paths. Git commands which create separate worktrees do that (e.g. `git submodule`).

`git worktree` does something a bit different because it has to support multiple worktrees. But depending on your use-case, you might be able to just use that command instead doing it manually.

Comment: By the way, for questions about Magit and other Emacs related things I recommend http://emacs.stackexchange.com.